# OpenShift, after installing Tomcat 8 no startup file

Tags: tomcat, openshift, tomcat8

I finished installing Tomcat 8 with a DIY application on OpenShift. Everything was good, the server start normally and i could see the tomcat page in the browser. But this morning when trying to start Tomcat folloying this steps:

```
rhc app ssh tomcat8
cd /tmp/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/bin
sh startup.sh && tail -f ../logs/*
```

like I've did after the installation was complete, **THE problem is the bin directory contains only derby.log**, there is no startup.sh or shutdown.sh files nothing but derby.log. I'm freaking out what's the problem !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to reinstall tomcat 8 following this tutorial  [here](https://blog.openshift.com/how-to-run-apache-tomcat-8-on-openshift/)  and to focus on step 10 which I didn't found in other tutorials, hope it helps!